# Codeigniter - Get value from database, then pass it to another function

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

So here is my get ticket function in my model:

```
function get_last_ticket(){

    $WorkBase = $this->session->userdata('cWorkBase');
    $this->db->where('cWorkBase',$WorkBase);
    $query = $this->db->get('tticketno');
    $ticketnow = "";
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

        $ticketnow = $row['nTicket'];
    }

    return $ticketnow;
}
```

Then I am trying to pass the value of that to this function:

```
function last_ticket(){
    if($this->session->userdata['cWorkBase'] == 'HO'){
        $TickLoc = 'H';
    }else{
        $TickLoc = 'S';
    }

    $timezone = "Asia/Manila";
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

    $year = date('y');
    $LastTicket = $this->get_last_ticket();
    $NextTicketNo = $TickLoc . $year . str_pad($LastTicket,5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return $NextTicketNo;
}
```

last_ticket() function is converting the int from my counter in the database from 1 to S1700001 then I pass the value to my insert function:

```
function submit_ticket(){
    $timezone = "Asia/Manila";
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $latestTicket = $this->last_ticket();

    $data = array(
            'cTicketNo' => var_dump($latestTicket),
            'vDepartment' => $this->session->userdata('vDepartment'),
            'cPCName' => $this->session->userdata('vName'),
            'cUsername' => $this->session->userdata('cUsername'),
            'vCategory' => $this->input->post('vCategory'),
            'vConcern' => $this->input->post('vConcern'),
            'vCaller' => $this->input->post('vCaller'),
            'dDateTimeCalled' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())
            );

    $this->db->insert('tconcerns',$data);


}
```

here's the database table:

table name: tticketno

[image: tticketno table]

Instead of getting S1700001, I am getting S1700000 but I have the number 1 in my database..

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this get_last_ticket function returning 1 or not .

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: $NextTicketNo = $TickLoc . $year . str_pad($LastTicket,5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT); what is the value of $LastTicket ?

Comment: Is column 'cTicketNo' is a primaru key with autoincrement ?

Comment: cTicketNo isn't autoincrement because I am putting my own ticket No on that column..

Comment: $LastTicket value should be the one from get_last_ticket(); function

Comment: Can you please dump variable : var_dump($LastTicket) on your last_ticket() method and tell us the result ?

Comment: Still the same, okay so the get_last_ticket function that I have is getting an int, like a counter for the ticket number. Do I need to convert it to string in my last_ticket function?

Comment: You need to do some tests to find where it's going wrong. Start by doing var_dump($latestTicket) in submit_ticket(), if that returns 1 start going through last_ticket with var_dump() to see where your value becomes 1

Comment: $WorkBase = $this->session->userdata('cWorkBase');
            $this->db->where('cWorkBase',$WorkBase);
     $query = $this->db->get('tticketno');
     $ticketnow = "";
     foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

      $ticketnow = $row->nTicket;
      $NextTicketNo = $TickLoc . $year . str_pad($ticketnow,5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
      return $NextTicketNo;
     }

I think that query is not returning anything

Comment: Just saw the end of your comment. Why do you think that? Did you try to var_dump something and you saw no value returned, or is it just a guess?

Comment: hmm, I tried to var_dump and it returned S1700000 .. what do you think is wrong?

Comment: Don't start in the beginning, start at the end. Start by doing var_dump($latestTicket) in submit_ticket()

Comment: yes, that's what I did and still S1700000 is appearing

Comment: That's odd. In your $data array, try hardcoding a test value like `'cTicketNo' => 'test'` and see if that saves correctly.

Comment: yes, I tried it and it inserted test.. I'm editing my question at the top and put the database columns so you get a better look..

I'm suspecting that the way I fetch the data is wrong..

Comment: I've edited my question and added the table

Comment: In the image you upload you show a column with nTicket, but in the $data array you store the value under cTicketNo, the two have to be the same for it to work correctly

Comment: No, in my data array it inserts into a different table.. the image I uploaded, that's where I get the get_last_ticket function that I pass to the last_ticket function

Comment: Ok. But if in the array you're trying to save to the db and $latestTicket is showing the correct value, that means everything you did before to get that value worked fine. It's strange things should go wrong from there, because there's not really much left that could go wrong. I'm about out of ideas, but just to check we understand each other, edit your question to show the line where you've made your var_dump($latestTicket) call

Comment: Not sure how you see the value that way, you're just trying to store the var_dump into the database. Remove the var_dump there and set it back to 'cTicketNo' => $latestTicket, then after the array and before the insert do var_dump($data);

Comment: Nothing's happening when I tried it.

Comment: I know what's wrong now I tried to remove the str_pad and just concatenate it with the $ticklock and $year. so i'll have $TickLock . $year . $ticketnow and guess what, the $ticketnow is returning as null..